# Add Lat and Long to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am new to Android. In my code i want to add 1000 Markers on my map. I know how to create the the array with Lat-long and i know how to create markers.

i create my markers like this:

```
protected void createMarker(Double latitude, Double longitude) {

        LatLng latLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLong)
               // .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));

    }
```

and add LatLog to my arrayList like this:

```
locations.add(new LatLng(-08.8123083,13.2249500));
locations.add(new LatLng(-08.8265861,13.2274667));
locations.add(new LatLng(-08.8328611,13.2182861));
```

My problem is that the way i add LaLng to my array i will get a lot of code if i add 1000 LatLong.
Please show the better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you store your lat long? if it is a txt file, you can create file reader and read it line by line and add marker automatically.

Comment: You can also use a database to store your latitude/logitudes

Comment: I tried it with the database but the markers did not show up

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the @Pso's comment, you can store all your Lat,Lng values in a JSON file and copy that file to the assets folder of your app.

So, let's say you save the data like this in `assets/locations.json` file,

```
    {
    "data": [
    [-08.8123083,13.2249500],
    [-08.8265861,13.2274667],
    [-08.8328611,13.2182861],
    ....]
   }
```

And then read it as,

```
public String getJSONFromAssets() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputData = getAssets().open("locations.json");
            int size = inputData.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputData.read(buffer);
            inputData.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

Use the JSON data anywhere in your code like,

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getJSONFromAssets());
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    if (arr != null)  
       for (int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
           locations.add(arr.get(i).toString());
```

Comment: in this way how can i add the title for the markers?

Comment: You can add title in the JSON file itself, if you've got those on hand. So instead of using the arrays of location, add another object which has title and array of locations. Basically you an keep on adding key/value pair in the JSON file as you please.

Comment: Thanks. i will try

Comment: i try to get LatLong from Sql server 2014 could you help me with my code to?

Comment: Please open a new question for that

Comment: in the line if (jArray != nul)
where this array come from?

Comment: My bad. Another victim of copy/paste. Fixed

Comment: how can i pass to my createMarker?

Comment: How were you doing earlier? Same way. Iterate through the locations ArrayList and call createMarker